# In jQuery get neighboring cell Data (Same Row) for each row link

Tags: jquery

I have a table with the structure

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="IDCol">
        Some data...
    </td>
    <td class="LinkCol">
        <a href="..">Link</a>
    </td>
    <!-- etc. -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

A jQuery iterator needs to go through all the links and capture the neighboring data in the corresponding Column IDCol to the left:

```
$('#myTable a[id^="linkIndex"]').off("click.linkIndex").on("click.linkIndex", function() {
   // here, need to get the corresponding "IDCol" contents for this link row
   var idContents = ...;
});
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `.next()` is your friend. https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Thanks but I'd prefer not to hard-code the column order, it's more reliable to find the column via a CSS class, it has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `a[id^="linkIndex"]` selector to be correct, try :

```
$('#myTable a[id^="linkIndex"]').off("click.linkIndex").on("click.linkIndex", function() {
   var idContents = $(this).closest("td").prev("td.IDCol").text(); // or maybe .html()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your link `td` has class `LinkCol`. Use this to iterate through each link and get the text of previous `td` using `prev()` function like following.

```
$('.LinkCol').each(function() {
    var idcol = $(this).prev('.IDCol').text();
    console.log(idcol);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is the solution, the only issue is that we can't use "prev" directly on the link as the TD is not sibling of "this" (a link), so we need to use "closest" as in Roamer's reply.

Comment: In your given html `.LinkCol` is the class of  `td` not `a`. So my solution should work perfectly if you are not using different html. See this https://jsfiddle.net/vjqvsacy/ @geneb.